# expansion of exterior derivative of interior product

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, lie-derivative

Let $\omega$ be an 1-form and $X$ be a vectorfield. As usual $i_X \omega$ denotes the interior product and $\mathrm d$. the exterior derivative.

Is there an expansion of the term
$$
\mathrm d (i_X \omega) \quad ?
$$

I would suspect that this can be expressed in terms of Lie-Derivatives, wedge-products and $i$ and $\mathrm d$ but I could not find anything in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cartan's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_a_differential_form) tells you that $\mathcal{L}_X \omega = di_X \omega + i_X d\omega$ (for forms of arbitrary degree).

If $\omega$ is a $1$-form, then $\iota_Xd\omega(Y) = d\omega(X,Y) = X\omega(Y) - Y\omega(X) - \omega([X,Y])$, hence you can further write
$$
di_X \omega(Y)=[\mathcal{L}_X,i_Y] \omega +\omega([X,Y]) + Y\omega(X)
$$

Comment: I have never seen the notation $[\mathcal L_x, i_Y]\omega$ before, but according to my calculations (and notation inference) this is the commuator $i_Y \mathcal L_X \omega - \mathcal L_X i_Y \omega$, right? (my only doubt is the ordering)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think with the identity $\omega([X, Y]) = -(\mathcal L_X, i_Y) \omega$, which I found in [this talk by Marsden from 2003](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/wiki/uploads/cds202-08/home/Differential_Forms.pdf) on Slide 40 the result can be simpliefied to $\mathrm d i_X \omega (Y) = Y \omega(X) = \mathcal L_Y (\omega(X))$. This is almost trivial since $\mathrm d i_X \omega (Y) = i_Y \mathrm d i_X \omega$ and $i_Y \mathrm d$ applied to the 0-Form $i_X \omega$ is the ordinary Lie-Derivative. -- I wonder if it is possible to express $\mathrm d (i_X \omega)$ without "using" $Y$

Comment: Yeah you're right, the long expression in my answer is a bit silly. It is really trivial that $di_X\omega(Y)=Y\omega(X)$. It seems like you're still unhappy about that. If you want a slick way of writing this down (i.e. without $Y$) , then $di_x\omega$ is perfectly fine. If you actually want to compute something, use $Y\omega(X)$. I don't think that there is anything more to hope for.